# How do you show the loading animation for windows phone 8.1 universal store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

When performing an async function to either get local data, access a file, or call an API, how do you trigger the loading animation during this, possibly, long routine?

Here's an example:

```
<Button onClick="Button_Click" />

public async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myData = await MyDataManager.GetMyData();
    await new MessageDiaglog("Data Loaded!").ShowAsync();
}
```

Since it's a universal store app, I assume it should work the same in both windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1.

**UPDATE FROM SOLUTION**

Per igrali answer, I updated my code for future reference:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="LoadingBar" Visibility="Collapsed" IsEnabled="False" IsIndeterminate="true" Height="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
<Button onClick="Button_Click" />

public async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadingBar.IsEnabled = true;
    LoadingBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    var myData = await MyDataManager.GetMyData();
    await new MessageDiaglog("Data Loaded!").ShowAsync();
    LoadingBar.IsEnabled = false;
    LoadingBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

This code will work on both the Phone and Tablet.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a pretty standardized way of doing this on Windows Phone. Since it's a Universal app, probably the best choice is to show a progress ring.

You add it in XAML

```
<ProgressRing IsActive="True"/>
```

You can show it either explicitly in code behind when button is clicked, or use a bool property in a viewmodel (if you use MVVM) and a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to show it or hide it by simply changing one property from true to false and vice versa.

I also suggest reading the official documentation [about progress controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780651.aspx) and I'll end this answer with a tip from ProgressRing documentation that [can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.progressring.isactive.aspx)

> Set the IsActive property to turn the ProgressRing on or off. If
>   IsActive is false, the ProgressRing is not shown, but space is
>   reserved for it in the UI layout. To not reserve space for the
>   ProgressRing, set it's Visibility property to Collapsed.
>
> Tip  When the ProgressRing is active, the progress animation continues
>   even if its not visible on the screen, such as when it's Visibility is
>   Collapsed. This can keep the UI thread awake, use resources, and
>   impair app performance. When the ProgressRing is not visible, you
>   should disable the animation by setting IsActive to false.

Comment: Ok great - so just to be clear, I activate/show it prior to the await call and then deactivate/hide it after the await call?

Comment: @EdenMachine exactly.